# Running jar with lots of different combinations of arguements automatically and storing output

Tags: java, jar, automation, autorun

I have a Java program and I want to test it with a lot of different combinations of arguments and store the output (System.out.print()'s) to see how it performs under different circumstances. I'm looking for a way to do it automatically. The arguments are all predefined strings which I can put into arrays.

What I want to do is basically this:

```
for (argument a in argumentArray1) 
    for (argument b in argumentArray2) 
        // more nested loops
            runAndStoreOutput("java -jar PATH_TO_MY_FILE " + a + " " + b /* + ... */);
```

Can I do this in Java? Should I? Are there any applications that allow me to do this easily?

Comment: For this problem I would propose to use a script (CMD or Shell, depending on your operating system) and not to start from within a JVM another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes sense to do this in Java if you want to periodically ensure your application works correctly e.g. after each change or each release. In this case you should write an unit test. If you want to do this, you should just test your applications Main method with an unit test and not test again the compiled jar file.

In order to create all possible combinations of arguments you could use google's guava like this:

```
Set<String> a = Sets.newHashSet("A", "B");
Set<String> b = Sets.newHashSet("1", "2");
Set<String> c = Sets.newHashSet("#", "+");
Set<List<String>> powerSet = Sets.cartesianProduct(a, b, c); // variable-length argument list
for (List<String> subSet : powerSet)
    System.out.println(subSet);
```

Output:

```
[A, 2, +]
[A, 2, #]
[A, 1, +]
[A, 1, #]
[B, 2, +]
[B, 2, #]
[B, 1, +]
[B, 1, #]
```

Or like this if you need the power set instead of a cartesian product:

```
Set<String> a = Sets.newHashSet("A", "B", "C");
Set<Set<String>> powerSet = Sets.powerSet(a);
for (Set<String> subSet : powerSet)
    System.out.println(subSet);
```

Output:

```
[]
[A]
[B]
[A, B]
[C]
[A, C]
[B, C]
[A, B, C]
```